# Azure DevOps - how to know a Resolved work item is actviely being tested (vs. in the queue)

Tags: scrum, agile, team-management, user-stories

## TLDR;

Does Azure DevOps have a recommended built in way of marking Resolved Work Items as being actively tested as opposed of being in the queue for testing?

## Details

My team is using Azure DevOps with Agile workflow.

This means that out-of-the box a user story goes through the following states

1. **New** -> Implementation started ->
2. **Active** -> Code complete ->
3. **Resolved** -> Acceptance tests passed ->
4. **Closed**

This is nicely shown at [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?view=azure-devops):

[image: user story states]

Testing happens in when the story (or bug) is in the Resolved state.

The out of the box board has 4 lanes.
[image]

When looking at the board (or even in queries) I'm having trouble seeing what is being actively tested.

For example, if there are 2 resolved items it is not clear which one is being actively worked on and which one is waiting to be picked up.

Showing what is being tested seems like a common desire and my intuition is that the solution for my problem is built in. I want to avoid customising the workflow (and adding a new state called Testing).

Answer (score 3):

Breaking down between development and testing could be dangerous, as you may fall into a mini waterfall process. Ideally you should have both developers and QA working together. In this sense, the "active" status would suffice.

Nevertheless, in case you want to have a specific state for testing, you'll need to use **[customised workflows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops).**

**Caution:** using custom workflows opens a Pandora's box you may not want to. For instance, people may start to consider status for "analysis", or "UAT", or "acceptance". These status could lead to a potentially misleading sensation of progress (*hey, we're in user acceptance already, it's almost there!*) when all you want is to have a story, functionality **delivering value** to end users.

Comment: RE: customised workflows. I really would prefer to not customise the flow.

Comment: While conceptually "Breaking down between development and testing could be dangerous" is very appealing, in my admittedly unimpressive career there have always been a distinct testing/QA stage.